# it's possible using javascript socket client in unity js script..?

Tags: javascript, sockets, node.js, socket.io, unity-game-engine

is the unity js script support for socket client using javascript ? or any something suggestion to use javascript socket client in unity?

i try socket.io library for javascript socket client but i don't know how to implement that in unity, any someone can explain that?

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

this code in htm page, i think i have idea to include taht script in unity but i can't found documentation for that...thanks for helping

Comment: socket.io is for a node server , are you using a nodejs server ? to handle socket.io messages ? what does it have to do with unity ?

Comment: yes in my plan i wanna to use socket.io with nodejs to server. and socket.io client to client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity's javascript is not real javascript. Unity's javascript is a different language called UnityScript, whose syntax is similar to original javascript.

UnityScript is based on Mono, a open source .Net framework implementation. so what you need is .Net socket, not socket.io.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx

For example, to create a TCP client socket in C#:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

In UnityScript:

```
var client : TcpClient = new TcpClient(server, port);
var stream : NetworkStream = client.GetStream();
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Different syntax, but the same API/library.

Comment: owh...in unity script i can't found to use web socket, if that using c# to using .net to create socket request how to implement that in unity javascript, is unity javscript can call method or function in C# ?

Comment: you can create socket in unity javascript, no need to use C#.

Comment: wow that is good sound, can you give me the reference for create socket ini unity javascript?